# Firestore Service Worker and push notifications

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-notifications

I've an Angular 5 (OSWindows 10) app and I've set up the manifest, sw (server worker file), updated angular-cli and index.html according to FCM documentation. Added senderid.  In my service worker file I'm calling 'firebase.initializeApp' with my messagingSenderId.

However, when I run the app I get the following error:
**"Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)."**

I have tried to add the following code (in my message.service), without success:

```
private _messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;
private messageSource = new Subject();
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable(); 

constructor(
private _afs: AngularFirestore,
@Inject(FirebaseApp) private _firebaseApp: firebase.app.App,
) {
this._messaging = firebase.messaging(this._firebaseApp);
}
```

...
I've also checked and there is no other sw running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call app initialize like here in the web setup:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

To be sure you have initialized app you can check like this:

```
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        //app not init do so now
        firebase.initializeApp(appConfig);
    }
```

Comment: Thx for the response, but I've done all that. This is about the SW, and not about Firestore as such. All the info is in the environment file. My problem is with the content in the firebase-message-sw.js fil, my service worker set up.

Comment: Tried to change the config exact. accord. to your instruct., but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding a Firebase init in app.module. The issue was a timing issues. Initiation happened to late, AFTER service was initated.